# Use external equinox jar for equinox container in Eclipse Project

Tags: eclipse, maven, osgi, osgi-bundle, equinox

I've created a project in eclipse and I want to use the equinox jars which are available in local repository i.e. I don't want to use equinox from eclipse. How can I achieve this?

For Example: If I create any project in eclipse and want to use OSGI framework then eclipse automatically uses the equinox jars which are available for that particular version of eclipse. But I don't want to use the eclipse's equinox jar. I want to specify some location for my project from where it can load the equinox jars.

Answer (score 0):

Add a dependency for a concrete version in your pom file. That will add the jar file to your class path and your application will use that concrete version